# php future date showing 1970-04-01 instead of 3 months after start date

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

I'm trying to take a date and add 3 months to it for use on an accounting system and we need to split the dates into quarters for our tax return

I have the following code

```
$e = ORM::for_table('sys_taxdate')->find_many();
```

This has been input into the database using a date type in the column and displys correctly as :

2016-07-02

I then want to add 3 months to this date so i can search the database for any invoices rasied between these 2 dates. The code i have tried is

```
    $idate = $e;
    $its = strtotime($idate);
    $dd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months', $its));
```

But $dd outputs the date 1970-04-01

I have looked over many posts and looks as though strtotime is not starting with the right date format, or at least thats what i think but have been trying for hours now and have hit a brick wall

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/601533). This means `$e` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: If i output $e directly it does display 2016-07-02

Comment: if you run `var_dump($e)` you get nothing output but `string(10) "2016-07-02"`?

Comment: Apologies, have you tried outputting variable $its

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I ended up getting the exact result from the database first

```
$e = ORM::for_table('sys_taxdate')->find_one(2);
$date = $e->get('taxdate');   


    $idate = $date;
    $its = strtotime($idate);
    $dd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months', $its));
```